# Get children of a node faster with Alfresco Api

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'm using the alfresco api on my Java backed webscript. I have an uuid, and I do a new NodeRef with this uuid and then I use getChildAssoc from NodeService to obtain all the direct child nodes. But on folders with more than 100 subfolders it takes too long. Are there another quicky way to obtain all direct children of a node? The fastest method you know to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `nodeService` or `NodeService`?

Comment: I'm using NodeService

Comment: Try with the little `n` version, it will skip things like transactions and permission checking. Depending on if that helps or not, it'll guide us to the best way for you to solve your issue